# Using a pseudo-element (::before) as jump link target not working in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, anchor, pseudo-element

I'm having an issue when using a pseudo-element (::before) as an anchor-link, because the page doesn't recognize it as the anchor, and keeps going to the section itself. I've tried every option suggested in [Nicolas Gallagher's](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/) blog, but nothing seems to work. The only difference I see in the blog's code is that I'm using flexbox for it to be a column and wrap the content.

This is the CSS I'm using

```
  #one, #two, #three {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  margin: 15em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: blue;
}
#one::before, #two::before, #three::before {
    background: red;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 150px;
    margin: -150px 0 0;
}
```

Thanks!

**....................................**

EDIT: Done! Already found an easier method: Having an "empty" (non-breaking space) anchor within the same section, invisible to the reader, and not colliding with the upper area margins.

HTML:

```
<div id="red-container">
    <a name="red-target">&nbsp;</a>
    Hello World!
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#red-container {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.5em;
  /** display and flex-flow are not neccesary, its just for visual context**/
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: red;
}
#red-container a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -6.6em;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

And here's the code in action: https://codepen.io/JS3DX/pen/bGEjZbK?editors=1100. Credits to [Calvin Spealman's](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/10/23/css-tip-fixed-headers-and-section-anchors/) blog for the answer to this issue.

Comment: Nicolas' post is from 2010 so it could be pretty outdated. Also as you can see in his demo he uses `:target'` pseudo selector instead the approach he described in the post, which is the exactly the thing you are looking for.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Placing a `scroll-margin-top: [px|em|rm]` inside the styling of the target solves this waaaaaay easier. It's just a margin/brake to the auto-scroll from the anchor to the anchor-link, so you just need to establish well enough how far away that scroll margin will be, or the size of the nav menu if it has `position: fixed` styling:

```
#one, #two, #three {
  scroll-margin-top: 1em;
}
```